# Spring Web Flow and Spring Security's CSRF

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, spring-webflow

How do I use Spring Security implementation of CSRF prevention in a Spring Web Flow module within my web application? I have configured org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy successfully for CSRF prevention but module using Spring Web flow is breaking.